# Java SpringBoot Build Failure when deploying in Azure - Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.1.0:deploy

Tags: java, maven, azure

This is my first time deploying a spring boot app in Azure. It's been days and I still don't know how I get this error every time I try to deploy my application. The app has no error or bug when run on localhost. Would really appreciate the help.

This is the error I get in the command line when I deploy the app.

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ graphql-sb ---
[INFO] Building jar: A:\Sandbox3D\sandbox\08 spring sample\workspace\graphql-sb\target\graphql-sb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.15.RELEASE:repackage (default) graphql-sb ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.1.0:deploy (default-cli) @ graphql-sb ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 28.425 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-22T17:10:13+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.1.0:deploy (default-cli) on project graphql-sb: Execution default-cli of goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.1.0:deploy failed: A required class was missing while executing com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.1.0:deploy: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.1.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-webapp-maven-plugin/1.1.0/azure-webapp-maven-plugin-1.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.3.0/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-builder-support/3.3.3/maven-builder-support-3.3.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/1.0.2.v20150114/aether-util-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.2.5/sisu-guice-3.2.5-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.21/plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.20/plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-maven-plugin-lib/1.0.0/azure-maven-plugin-lib-1.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/3.0.0/maven-filtering-3.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.0.0/maven-shared-utils-3.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.7/plexus-build-api-0.0.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure/1.9.0/azure-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-client-runtime/1.4.0/azure-client-runtime-1.4.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/rest/client-runtime/1.4.0/client-runtime-1.4.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/20.0/guava-20.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/squareup/retrofit2/retrofit/2.1.0/retrofit-2.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.4.2/okhttp-3.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.9.0/okio-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okhttp3/logging-interceptor/3.4.2/logging-interceptor-3.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp-urlconnection/3.4.2/okhttp-urlconnection-3.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/squareup/retrofit2/converter-jackson/2.1.0/converter-jackson-2.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.7.2/jackson-databind-2.7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-joda/2.7.2/jackson-datatype-joda-2.7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.7.0/jackson-annotations-2.7.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/squareup/retrofit2/adapter-rxjava/2.1.0/adapter-rxjava-2.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-client-authentication/1.4.0/azure-client-authentication-1.4.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/adal4j/1.1.2/adal4j-1.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/nimbusds/oauth2-oidc-sdk/4.5/oauth2-oidc-sdk-4.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.4.7/mail-1.4.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/net/jcip/jcip-annotations/1.0/jcip-annotations-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/net/minidev/json-smart/1.1.1/json-smart-1.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/nimbusds/lang-tag/1.4/lang-tag-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/3.1.2/nimbus-jose-jwt-3.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.51/bcprov-jdk15on-1.51.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-annotations/1.2.0/azure-annotations-1.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-resources/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-resources-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.5/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/io/reactivex/rxjava/1.2.4/rxjava-1.2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.5/httpcore-4.4.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[47] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-storage/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-storage-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[48] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-network/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-network-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[49] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-compute/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-compute-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[50] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-graph-rbac/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-graph-rbac-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[51] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-keyvault/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-keyvault-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[52] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-keyvault/1.0.0/azure-keyvault-1.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[53] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-keyvault-webkey/1.0.0/azure-keyvault-webkey-1.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[54] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-batch/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-batch-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[55] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-trafficmanager/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-trafficmanager-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[56] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-dns/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-dns-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[57] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-redis/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-redis-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[58] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-appservice/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-appservice-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[59] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-storage/6.1.0/azure-storage-6.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[60] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.0/jackson-core-2.6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[61] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-keyvault-core/0.8.0/azure-keyvault-core-0.8.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[62] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-locks/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-locks-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[63] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-eventhub/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-eventhub-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[64] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-cdn/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-cdn-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[65] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-sql/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-sql-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[66] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-containerinstance/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-containerinstance-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[67] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-containerregistry/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-containerregistry-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[68] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-containerservice/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-containerservice-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[69] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-cosmosdb/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-cosmosdb-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[70] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-search/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-search-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[71] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-msi/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-msi-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[72] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-monitor/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-monitor-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[73] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-servicebus/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-servicebus-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[74] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.1/joda-time-2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[75] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-mgmt-batchai/1.9.0/azure-mgmt-batchai-1.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[76] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/applicationinsights-core/1.0.9/applicationinsights-core-1.0.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[77] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/eu/infomas/annotation-detector/3.0.4/annotation-detector-3.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[78] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[79] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[80] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.3/httpclient-4.5.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[81] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[82] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[83] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/commons-net/commons-net/3.6/commons-net-3.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[84] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[85] = file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>graphql-sb</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>graphql-sb</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.15.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <authentication>
                    <serverId>azure-auth</serverId>
                </authentication>
                <appName>graphql-sb</appName>
                <resourceGroup>Java-SpringBoot-MongoDB</resourceGroup>                   
                <javaVersion>1.8</javaVersion>
                <javaWebContainer>tomcat 8.5</javaWebContainer>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're missing your Azure credentials in settings.xml. 
But you're getting this strange error (and nothing that points to the actual problem) because you're probably running JDK 11 that doesn't contain javax/xml/bind/JAXBException. This has been deprecated for a while and now it's been removed. 
The solution is to add a few dependencies to your azure-webapp-maven-plugin in your pom.xml, like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <authentication>
                    <serverId>azure-auth</serverId>
                </authentication>
                <resourceGroup>maven-plugin</resourceGroup>
                <appName>maven-web-app-${maven.build.timestamp}</appName>
                <region>westus</region>
                <javaVersion>1.8</javaVersion>
                <deploymentType>ftp</deploymentType>
                <stopAppDuringDeployment>true</stopAppDuringDeployment>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.jar</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <includes>
                            <include>web.config</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

This way your plugin will be able to look at your XML configuration and point you to the real problem. Mine was settings.xml missing the Azure authentication info.